# Scroll or slide functionlity in ionic framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

I have tried like below but the scroll/slide is not working.

```
<ion-slide-box show-pager="false">
                    <ion-slide ng-repeat="at in assets" ng-init="updateSlider()">
                        <div class="home-box">{{at.Asset_Name}}</div>
                    </ion-slide>
                </ion-slide-box>
```

in the above code i can display one div per one slide. But i want to display divs(2-3) as per the width. Like scroll. I tried with ion-scroll also, but it is not working. Is there any javascript or angular directive to use in this case? or any working code available in jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: I can't understand with this html?Will give more details what is your code? Which framework you are using if any?

Comment: Hi i have edited the content, is that understandable?

Comment: Still didn't understand?...Can you show some example